# How to change icon library (and picker) to custom library

Tags: joomla-3.x, gantry, icon

If I wanted to change from font-awesome to a custom icon library, what would be the steps necessary.   I will be using icomoon to generate the svg files and/or font - whichever is necessary.

My goal is to have this available using the icon picker, so all the instructions to complete this would be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked "[Using the Icon Picker](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/using-the-icon-picker)" ?

Comment: Yes and that's a great article on how to use the Icon Picker with Font Awesome.  However, it does not tell you how to add custom icons to Font Awesome or how to change from Font Awesome to another Icon set (such as a custom one from icomoon)